# Como passar valores de array por AJAX, via POST?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post

Boa pessoal!
Estou a criar uma função para inserir os dados de um formulário na BD (AJAX - POST):

```html
function inserir_registo()
{

    //dados a enviar, vai buscar os valores dos campos que queremos enviar para a BD
    
    
   var dadosajax = {
        'nome' : $("#nome").val(),
        'apelido' : $("#apelido").val(),
        'sexo' : $("#sexo").val(),
        'idade' : $("#idade").val(),
        'morada' : $("#morada").val(),
        'contacto' : $("#contacto").val(),
        'email' : $("#email").val(),
        'habilitacoes' : $("#habilitacoes").val(),
        'restricoes_alimentares' : $("#restricoes_alimentares").val(),
        //'areas' : $("areas[]").val(),
        
        'disponivelSexta' : $("#nomeSacado").val(),
        'disponivelSabado' : $("#nomeSacadoSabado").val(),
        'disponivelDomingo' : $("#nomeSacadoDomingo").val(),
        'transporte' : $("#transporte").val(),
        'voluntarioAPPACDM' : $("#voluntarioAPPACDM").val(),
        'autorizaImagem' : $("#autorizaImagem").val()
    };
    pageurl = 'roda.php';
    //para consultar mais opcoes possiveis numa chamada ajax
    //http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    $.ajax({
 
        //url da pagina
        url: pageurl,
        //parametros a passar
        data: dadosajax,
        //tipo: POST ou GET
        type: 'POST',
        //cache
        cache: false,
        //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
        //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
        },
        //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
        success: function(result)
        { 
            //se foi inserido com sucesso
            if($.trim(result) == '1')
            {
    alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
            }
            //se foi um erro
            else
            {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Como eu faço para ir buscar os valores deste exemplo de checkbox's (areas[]) e passá-los na `var dadosajax`?

HTML CHECKBOX'S:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Áreas de Interesse: </label><br>
                    <input id="interesse1" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="bilheteira">Bilheteira<br>
                    <input id="interesse2" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="guarda-roupa">Guarda-Roupa<br>
                    <input id="interesse3" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="venda de artesanato">Venda de artesanato<br>
                    <input id="interesse4" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="restauracao">Restauração<br>
                    <input id="interesse5" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="figuracao">Figuração<br>
                    <input id="interesse6" type="checkbox" name="areas[]" value="legiao">Legião<br>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um array percorrendo, pelo `name`, os checkboxes marcados e envie como valor em `'areas'`. No início da função coloque:

```
var areas = [];
$("[name='areas[]']:checked").each(function(i,e){
   areas.push(e.value)
});
```

E em no parâmetro `'areas'`, coloque:

```
'areas' : areas,
```

No backend o valor de `areas` será recebido como uma array com os valores dos checkboxes marcados.